# Text not loading in canvas image using Discord.js and node-canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a welcome message for my Discord server using Discord.js and node-canvas. I have an image as the background, and I want to add some text to it to greet new members when they join the server.

However, despite my best efforts, the text is not showing up in the canvas image. I've tried using the latest version of the AttachmentBuilder class, but that hasn't solved the problem.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const Canvas = require('@napi-rs/canvas');
const {Client, IntentsBitField, AttachmentBuilder} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ]
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome');
    if (!channel) return;
    
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
    // Load the background image and draw it to the canvas
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/discordjs/guide/main/guide/popular-topics/images/canvas.jpg')
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    // Set the color of the stroke
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#0099ff';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
    ctx.font = '30px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`Welcome to the server, ${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 2);
  
    const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(await canvas.encode('png'), { name: 'profile-image.png' });
    channel.send({ files: [attachment] });
  });

  
client.login(API_KEY)
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!